# Summing over a list

Tags: summation

I intend to sum a series over two lists which I generate myself. However, my code is not working. What is the best way to do this? Thanks. Find my code below

```
w = {5, 1, 2, 2, 8}; 
x = {0.5, 0.8, 4.6, 3.2, 5}; 
r = 1; 
mysum = Sum[
  w[i]*Exp[10^(((-Sqrt[2])*2*x[i] - 2*r)/10)], {i, 1, Length[w]}]
```

**Edit 1**
Further to this question, Let's suppose r is a list. How do I sum over to this list to my results equal to the length of r.

The code is below

```
w = {5, 1, 2, 2, 8};
x = {0.5, 0.8, 4.6, 3.2, 5};
r = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
mysum = Map[Total[w[*Exp[10^(((-Sqrt[2])*2*x - 2*r)/10)]], r]
```

Comment: replace  `w[i]` with `w[[i]]` and `x[i]` with `x[[i]]`

Comment: You can also use the `Dot` function, as  `w . Exp[10^(((-Sqrt[2])*2*x - 2*r)/10)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach. Consider that many numeric Mathematica functions are `Listable`. Look at the following

```
w = {5, 1, 2, 2, 8};
x = {0.5, 0.8, 4.6, 3.2, 5};
r = 1;

Sqrt[w]
(* {Sqrt[5], 1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2], 2 Sqrt[2]} *)
```

You provide a list to `Sqrt` and it knows that it needs to be applied on each element. If you know this, you can use exactly the same in your expression and *then* you sum all elements together using `Total`

```
Total[w*Exp[10^(((-Sqrt[2])*2*x - 2*r)/10)]]
(* 21.7645 *)
```